# Normal to hyperbola at any point P on it

Tags: geometry

P is a point on the hyperbola x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1, N is the foot of perpendicular from P on the transverse axis. The tangent to the hyperbola at P meets transverse axis at The. If O be the centre of the hyperbola, OT.ON is?

I actually tried solving it by finding the equation normal at parametric point P and putting y= 0 but got a different answer. Just tell me why the answer I'm getting is wrong?

Comment: The basic approach that you described seems correct. Show us your calculations, and someone can probably tell you where they went wrong.

Comment: Does this help:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167958/show-that-pf-pg-b2-in-a-hyperbola?rq=1